# how to unit-test if a cancellationTokenSource got cancelled

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cancellationtokensource

I want to make a unit-test to check if a cancellationTokenSource got cancelled for a timer.

This is my timer code:

```
public class RunTimer
    {
        public bool IsTimeLeft { get; private set; } = true;
        public static void Timer(int numberOfSeconds)
        {
            var whenToStop = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(numberOfSeconds);
            while (DateTime.Now < whenToStop)
            {
                string timeLeft = (whenToStop - DateTime.Now).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                WriteToScreen($"Time Remaining: {timeLeft}", true);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            if (DateTime.Now >= whenToStop)
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
        }

        static CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        readonly CancellationToken cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        public Task timerTask;
        public RunTimer(int numberOfSeconds)
        {
            timerTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Timer(numberOfSeconds);
                }
                timerTask = null;
                IsTimeLeft = false;
                cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            }, cancellationToken);
        }
        public void StopTimer(int numberOfQuestionsLeft)
        {
            if(numberOfQuestionsLeft == 0)
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my method where I use the timerThread:

```
public static OperationQuestionScore RunTest(int numberOfQuestionsLeft, UserDifficulty userDifficulty, int numberOfSeconds)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            var (operationMin, operationMax) = GetPossibleOperationsByDifficulty(userDifficulty);
            var score = new OperationQuestionScore();
            RunTimer RunWithTimer = new RunTimer(numberOfSeconds);

            while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0 && RunWithTimer.IsTimeLeft)
            {
                int mathRandomOperation = random.Next(operationMin, operationMax);
                MathOperation mathOperation = (MathOperation)mathRandomOperation;
                var (message, correctAnswer) = GetMathsEquation(mathOperation, userDifficulty);
                if (mathRandomOperation == 4 || mathRandomOperation == 6)
                {
                    WriteToScreen($"To the nearest integer, What is {message} =", false);
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteToScreen($"What is {message} =", false);
                }

                double userAnswer = Convert.ToDouble(ReadInput());
                if (Math.Round(correctAnswer) == userAnswer)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    WriteToScreen("Well Done!", false);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    score.Increment(mathOperation, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    WriteToScreen("Your answer is incorrect!", false);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    score.Increment(mathOperation, false);
                }
                numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                RunWithTimer.StopTimer(numberOfQuestionsLeft);
            }
            return score;
        }
```

This is the unit test code I have tried:

```
[Test]
        public void IsTimerCancellationRequested()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            //I set the numberOfQuestions to 0 so the StopTimer method is called and the cts is cancelled
            Program.RunTest(0, UserDifficulty.Easy, 30);
            Assert.That(cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        }
```

The problem is, is that the cts that I am using in the unit-test is not the same as the one in my timer method. But I am not sure how to fix it.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The first problem you have is that you should not test `RunTest` and `RunTimer` in the same test, otherwise you're not unit testing. My suggestion is to test them separately which involves mocking `RunTimer`

Comment: Then when testing `RunTimer` I would even mock `DateTime` since testing something relying on time is not very practical